# how to use htmlparsing and curl in JAVA for this task...?

Tags: java, search, parsing, text, curl

I'm trying to write a program that takes company names from a text file and searches them on a search engine website (SEC's Edgar search). Each search usually comes up with 1-10 unique search result links and so I want to use curl to click on the link with the relevant company name. The link page has a brief summary with the term "state of incorporation:" and then the state name. Im hoping to parse the state name. I am having trouble understanding how to use HTML parsing and curl and their classes. I would appreciate any help possible such as a brief outline of steps or just any advice at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the HTML is fairly basic, use something like the [Mozilla Java HTML Parser](http://mozillaparser.sourceforge.net/).  The [getting started guide](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) will give you more details on creating the DOM.  Java has [builtin APIs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html) for downloading content from the web, and these will likely be sufficient for you (rather than using "curl").

Once you have a DOM, you can use the standard DOM APIs to navigate for the links and items that you want.